# Why does zxc.io goes to 127.0.0.5?

Tags: ip-link-local

So i was searching for an .io domain but suddenly i tried going to zxc.io and suddenly my local server shows.

A trace route shows this

`Tracing route to zxc.io [127.0.0.5]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  127.0.0.5
Trace complete.`

Can somebody explain why [zxc.io](http://zxc.io) redirects to localhost?
Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here, as are questions about networks you do not directly control. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone just registered a domain zxc.io and set its A record to 127.0.0.5. It doesn't mean that it's some kind of special or "predefined in the system" domain. Just as a domain.com might have A record with valid public IP address, it could also have A record with 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.5. Someone just felt like buying this domain and configuring it like that, maybe it is usefull for this someone on his local network, and instead of setting local domain he bought public domain.

You asked if there should be a DNS request - I don't understand the question, but yeah, by doing `dig zxc.io` you are doing DNS request. The same is happening while typing zxc.io in your browser - your browser is asking the system for zxc.io and your system is doing the DNS request, and then return to the browser A record of this domain - in this case 127.0.0.5.

Sometimes RBLs (real-time blackhole lists) use different DNS A records to show if particular IP address is blacklisted or not, or whitelisted. For example if you do `dig +short 4.3.2.1.zen.spamhaus.org` you're checking if IP 1.2.3.4 is being blacklisted on spamhaus or not (IPs are written backwards as you can see, but it is a different story as of why), depends if it will return 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.2. Here is [more info about it in case of spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage) but if you don't know what RBLs are, you should read about it first. This said, zxc.io does not look like RBL. I just wrote about it as something slightly related :)

Answer (score 4):

Because someone put it into DNS?

Best to ask the people responsible:

```
$ dig SOA  zxc.io  +short
dns1.pointhq.com. **admin.pointhq.com**. 2018071902 7200 900 1209600 300
```

The admins should be reachable via admin@pointhq.com

Comment: Im no networking expert, but shouldnt there be a DNS request? I know this is a stupid question but its been boggling me for a long time.

Comment: @Melun, IP packets only have addresses, not names, in them, so when you try to use the name, your host will generate a DNS request to resolve the name to the address in order to complete the task. The bottom line is that there will always be some type of name to address resolution when using a name, and it is usually a DNS request, but it can sometimes be resolved some other way, e.g. with a hosts file.